# Problems with sizing on mobile site

Tags: html, css

I'm currently in the process of developing a mobile site for a fully functioning desktop site. Using media queries, I'm able get the actual content area to size down when on a display such as an iPhone or iPod. However, the rest of the page such as the footer and header do not want to size down correctly. Any advice? You can view the site here: www.tobynews.com

Comment: are you using any inline styles (inside HTML tags as <div style="height:0;">) on your header/footer/other elements? If so they will have priority over any css rules. Also, be wary of the order of your media queries. In some cases, rules lower down with have priority over rules higher up!

Answer (score 0):

footer if it works, the body does not

use `%` and `min` or `max`

```
#content {
    /*you css*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px;/* use % for size
    max-width: you size;
    min-width: you size;*/
}
```

**image auto**

```
body{
    background-image: url(uno.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* and you css*/
}
```

**detected size screen**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px){
  footer{
    width: /*you size*/;
  }
}
```